# Recursively list directory content, plus check if file is directory

Tags: linux, assembly, x86, nasm

I'm trying to learn assembly, so bear with me if my problems are elementary

The following code scans a directory and prints out all files and directories in it, except those starting with a dot. It seems to work fine.

However, once I uncomment the `call scandir` line to turn on recursion, it prints out a long list of repeating filenames (see below for details).

Also, I'd like a way to test if the file is a directory or not. How would I do that? As far as I can tell that isn't the problem, for now, since if it's not a directory the call to scandir will just return without doing anything, but the check might become important later on (and it seems a good thing to do anyway).

```
[SECTION .data]
DirName     db 'test', 0

[SECTION .bss]

[SECTION .text]

extern puts                  ; Externals from glibc standard C library
extern opendir               ; Externals from dirent.h
extern closedir
extern readdir

global main


scandir:
    pushad                  ; Save caller's registers

    push eax                ; Directory is passed in eax
    call opendir            ; Open directory
    add esp, 4
    cmp eax, 0              ; opendir returns 0 on failure
    je .done

    mov ebx, eax            ; Move directory handle to ebx

    .read:
        push ebx            ; Push directory handle
        call readdir        ; Read a file from directory
        add esp, 4          ; Clean up the stack
        cmp eax, 0          ; readdir returns 0 on failure or when done
        je .close

        add eax, 11         ; File name is offset at 11 bytes

        mov cl, byte [eax]  ; Get first char of filename
        cmp cl, 46          ; Ignore files and dirs which begin with a dot
        je .read            ; (., .., and hidden files)

        ;call scandir       ; Call scandir recursively
                            ; If file is not a dir opendir will simply fail

        push eax
        call puts
        add esp, 4

        jmp .read

    .close:
        push ebx                ; Close directory
        call closedir
        add esp, 4
        jmp .done

    .done:
        popad                   ; Restore caller's registers
        ret

main:
    push ebp                ; Set up stack frame for debugger
    mov ebp, esp
    push ebx                ; Must preserve ebp, ebx, esi and edi
    push esi
    push edi
    ; start

    mov eax, DirName
    call scandir

    ; end
    pop edi                 ; Restore saved registers
    pop esi
    pop ebx
    mov esp, ebp            ; Destroy stack frame
    pop ebp
    ret
```

The directory structure of the test directory is like this:

```
bar [directory]
    bas.c
test1.c
test2.c
test3.c
foo.txt
test
```

Without recursion it prints out the files in the test directory as it should, but with recursion it seems to print the following:

```
test1.c
bar
test3.c
[repeat 3 lines ~1000 times]
test
foo.txt
test2.c
[repeat 3 lines ~1000 times]
```

**Edit:** This now mostly works, I think, except that it seems to jump back into the directory below 'test' initially, causing it to list the files there and the files in 'test' twice

```
[SECTION .data]
ParentDir   db '..', 0
CurrentDir  db '.', 0
DirName     db 'test', 0

[SECTION .bss]

[SECTION .text]
extern puts                 ; Externals from glibc standard C library
extern opendir              ; Externals from dirent.h
extern closedir
extern readdir
extern chdir

global main

scandir:
    pushad                  ; Save caller's registers

    push eax                ; Directory is passed in eax
    call opendir            ; Open directory
    add esp, 4
    cmp eax, 0              ; opendir returns 0 on failure
    je .done

    mov ebx, eax            ; Move directory handle to ebx

    .read:
        push ebx            ; Push directory handle
        call readdir        ; Read a file from directory
        add esp, 4          ; Clean up the stack
        cmp eax, 0          ; readdir returns 0 on failure or when done
        je .close

        add eax, 11         ; File name is offset at 11 bytes

        mov cl, byte [eax]  ; Get first char of filename
        cmp cl, 46          ; Ignore files and dirs which begin with a dot
        je .read            ; (., .., and hidden files)

        cmp byte [eax-1], 4
        jne .notdir

        push eax
        call chdir
        add esp, 4
        mov eax, CurrentDir
        call scandir        ; Call scandir recursively
        jmp .read

    .notdir:
        push eax
        call puts
        add esp, 4

        jmp .read

    .close:
        push ebx                ; Close directory
        call closedir
        add esp, 4

        push ParentDir
        call chdir
        add esp, 4

        jmp .done

    .done:
        popad                   ; Restore caller's registers
        ret

main:
    push ebp                ; Set up stack frame for debugger
    mov ebp, esp
    push ebx                ; Must preserve ebp, ebx, esi and edi
    push esi
    push edi
    ; start

    mov eax, DirName
    call scandir

    ; end
    pop edi                 ; Restore saved registers
    pop esi
    pop ebx
    mov esp, ebp            ; Destroy stack frame
    pop ebp
    ret
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks almost fine. The problem is with the path name returned by `readdir`, which you want to use for the next recursive step. The path name returned is not relative to the current working directory.

The massive output you're seeing is when the `test/` directory contains a file named `test`. When your loop sees that filename, you will pass it to `opendir` which means you simply reopen the same `test/` directory again, causing infinite recursion until you run out of file handles.

One way to solve this is to call `chdir` after a successful `opendir` (and also `chdir` back to the parent directory after `closedir`) so that the working directory will always point to the one you're currently inspecting.

---

> Also, I'd like a way to test if the file is a directory or not.

The `dirent` structure returned by [readdir](http://linux.die.net/man/3/readdir) has a `d_type` member (at offset 10) that you can check:

```
...
call readdir
...
cmp byte [eax+10], 4    ; DT_DIR = 4
jne is_not_directory
```

Comment: Thanks. I think I have it mostly working now, but it's still causing me some trouble. See the edit in my post above.

Comment: Still the same problem - you start off by listing the `test/` directory and then treat those paths as relative to the current working directory, which they are not. A quick fix (in `main`) would be to `chdir` into `DirName` and then `mov eax, CurrentDir` before you `call scandir`

Comment: Ah! Or I just move the `chdir` part to the start of `scandir`. Thank you for the help, it's working now

Comment: Another good way to handle this is with `openat` (https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html), where you can use a relative path relative to an open directory FD instead of having to `chdir` in and `chdir` back again on the way out.  That prevents having symlinks to directories make chdir("foo") / `chdir("..")` take you somewhere else.

Comment: Also, `d_type` is an optional optimization that some filesystems don't fill in.  Reliable code *must* handle `DT_UNKNOWN` if they want to work on FAT, older XFS, and some other filesystems.  [Checking if a dir. entry returned by readdir is a directory, link or file. dent->d\_type isn't showing the type](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29094555)