# Checking if a dir. entry returned by readdir is a directory, link or file. dent->d_type isn't showing the type

Tags: c, linux, readdir, opendir, dirent.h

I am making a program which is run in a Linux shell, and accepts an argument (a directory), and displays all the files in the directory, along with their type.

Output should be like this:

```
 << ./Program testDirectory

 Dir directory1
 lnk linkprogram.c
 reg file.txt
```

If no argument is made, it uses the current directory. Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  struct stat info;
  DIR *dirp;
  struct dirent* dent;

  //If no args
  if (argc == 1)
  {

    argv[1] = ".";
    dirp = opendir(argv[1]); // specify directory here: "." is the "current directory"
    do
    {
      dent = readdir(dirp);
      if (dent)
      {
        printf("%c ", dent->d_type);
        printf("%s \n", dent->d_name);

        /* if (!stat(dent->d_name, &info))
         {
         //printf("%u bytes\n", (unsigned int)info.st_size);

         }*/
      }
    } while (dent);
    closedir(dirp);

  }

  //If specified directory 
  if (argc > 1)
  {
    dirp = opendir(argv[1]); // specify directory here: "." is the "current directory"
    do
    {
      dent = readdir(dirp);
      if (dent)
      {
        printf("%c ", dent->d_type);
        printf("%s \n", dent->d_name);
        /*  if (!stat(dent->d_name, &info))
         {
         printf("%u bytes\n", (unsigned int)info.st_size);
         }*/
      }
    } while (dent);
    closedir(dirp);

  }
  return 0;
}
```

For some reason `dent->d_type` is not displaying the type of file. I'm not really sure what to do, any suggestions?

Comment: Good to know! I'll keep that in mind. Any idea on the d_type not working?

Comment: What does readdir return? You should be checking the return values more carefully, it may give you a clue.

Comment: I'm not really sure what dent->d_type is meant to return, but at the moment it's not returning anything

Comment: regarding what's in d_type, have you checked the man page? There are some constants defined.

Comment: On which platform do you observe this.

Comment: I'm using red hat linux

Comment: Just out of couriosity: How did this issue resolve?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

`d_type` is a speed optimization to save on `lstat(2)` calls, when it's supported.

As the [`readdir`(3) man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/readdir) points out, not all filesystems return real info in the `d_type` field (typically because it would take an extra disk seek to read the inode, as is the case for XFS if you didn't use `mkfs.xfs -n ftype=1` (implied by `-m crc=1` which is not yet the default).  Filesystems that always set `DT_UNKNOWN` are common in real life, and not something that you can ignore.  XFS is not the only example.

You always need code that will fall back to using [`lstat`(2)](http://linux.die.net/man/2/lstat) if `d_type==DT_UNKNOWN`, if the filename alone isn't enough to decide it's uninteresting.  (This is the case for some callers, like `find -name` or expanding globs like `*.c`, which is why `readdir` doesn't incur the overhead of filling it in if it would take an extra disk read.)

The Linux [`getdents(2)`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/getdents64) man page has an example program that does what you're trying to do, including a chained-ternary-operator block to decode the `d_type` field into text strings.  (As the other answers point out, your mistake is printing it out as an character, rather than comparing it against `DT_REG`, `DT_DIR`, etc.)

Anyway, the other answers mostly covered things, but missed the critical detail that you **NEED a fallback** for the case when `d_type == DT_UNKNOWN` (0 on Linux.  `d_type` is stored in what used to be a padding byte, until Linux 2.6.4).

To be portable, your code needs to check that `struct dirent` even HAS a `d_type` field, if you use it, or your code **won't even compile** outside of GNU and BSD systems. (see `readdir(3)`)

---

I wrote **an example for [finding directories with readdir](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39430337/224132)**, using `d_type` with a fallback to `stat` when d_type isn't available at compile time, when it's DT_UNKNOWN, and for symlinks.

Comment: FYI: XFS has defaulted to `-m crc=1` for several years, at least since `xfsprogs 3.3`.

Answer (score 9):

The `d_type` in the return struct gives a number for the type. You can't print that directly because the used values are not printable when interpreted as ASCII (for example they are 4 for dirs and 8 for files.).

You can either print them as numbers like this:

```
printf("%d ", dent->d_type)
```

Or compare them to the constants like `DT_DIR` and construct some meaningful output from that, like a char type:

```
if(dent->type == DT_DIR) type = 'd'
```

Comment: Thanks for your input, I tried this and received no output. I also tried == DT_LNK and == DT_REG for regular files and link files, no luck though.

Comment: In my case that worked. You have to be aware that the type is not provided by all file systems, and is not mentioned in posix. What file system are you on ?

Comment: I'm running Red Hat Linux and using the default shell

Answer (score 3):

Print `d_type` as an integer like so:

```
printf("%d ", dent->d_type);
```

and you'll see meaningful values.

Comment: thank you! This is somewhat helpful, I am now receiving 0's for all of my things in the directory regardless of type. Hmm, this is confusing!

Comment: I am also find all my directorys in my android phone , d_type is always 0. can you give me some help to fix it ?

Answer (score 3):

I was able to use d_type on ubuntu:

```
    switch (readDir->d_type)
    {
    case DT_DIR:
        printf("Dir: %s\n", readDir->d_name);
        break;
    case DT_REG:
        printf("File: %s\n", readDir->d_name);
        break;
    default:
        printf("Other: %s\n", readDir->d_name);
    }
```

The list of entry types can be found in dirent.h, (this could be different for os other than ubuntu):

dirent.h

```
#define DT_UNKNOWN       0
#define DT_FIFO          1
#define DT_CHR           2
#define DT_DIR           4
#define DT_BLK           6
#define DT_REG           8
#define DT_LNK          10
#define DT_SOCK         12
#define DT_WHT          14
```

Comment: If it's `DT_UNKNOWN`, you need to fall back to `lstat` or `stat`.  `d_type` is only useful as an optimization, not guaranteed to be set.  See my answer here, and working code in my answer on [How to list first level directories only in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39430337)