# readdir returning dirent with d_type == DT_UNKNOWN for directories . and

Tags: c, linux, operating-system, posix, readdir

I have the following code that mimicks `ls`:

```
#include <dirent.h>
#include <stdio.h>

char* dirent_type_to_str(unsigned char dirent_type) {
  switch (dirent_type) {
  case DT_DIR:
    return "Dir ";
  case DT_REG:
    return "File";
  }

  printf("DEBUG: Unknown type %x\n", dirent_type);
  return "Unk ";
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  char* dir_path = argc > 1 ? argv[1] : ".";
  DIR* dir_stream = opendir(dir_path);

  struct dirent* dirent_ptr;
  while (dirent_ptr = readdir(dir_stream)) {
    printf("%s %s\n", dirent_type_to_str(dirent_ptr->d_type), dirent_ptr->d_name);
  }

  closedir(dir_stream);

  return 0;
}
```

For some reason, when I run the program, it is saying that the `d_type` associated with `.` and `..` is unknown:

```
james.ko@cslab1-20:~/Desktop/systems-11-02$ ./main
DEBUG: Unknown type 0
Unk  .
DEBUG: Unknown type 0
Unk  ..
File .gitignore
File main.o
File Makefile~
File Makefile
File main.c
Dir  .git
File main
File main.c~
```

From my research, it appears that `0` is equal to `DT_UNKNOWN` according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29094555/4077294). Why is this happening (instead of it yielding `DT_DIR`)?

Comment: FWIW you can simply hard-code knowledge that . and .. are directories. They are mandated by POSIX.

Comment: My answer that you linked to already explains why the kernel might choose to leave `DT_UNKNOWN`: if it would have required extra I/O to read the type from the inode because it wasn't stored in the directory itself, it doesn't spend time doing that in case the caller wasn't going to need it, or was going to `lstat` anyway.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The manpage for `readdir()` clearly states, that a filesystem is free to return `DT_UNKNOWN` in the `struct dirent`:

> Currently, only some filesystems (among them: Btrfs, ext2, ext3, and ext4) have full support for returning the file type in d_type.  All applications must properly handle  a return of DT_UNKNOWN.

This is mainly done for performance reasons, because with some filesystems the file type is *not* stored in the directory itself. In this case, for large directories, many reads scattered over the whole block device would slow down readdir() significantly.

So, if you really need the d_type on a filesystem, which does not fill it properly, you will have to call `(l)stat()` explicitly.

Comment: XFS is a perfect example of a malefactor in this case.

Comment: [Current XFS supports `d_type`.](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=0cb97766f2928579f1029ea7b28ae946cdd6fbe1)